# When plotting two maps on top of each other, how to reduce the horizontal spacing between two vertical legends

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I have the following code which plots three graphs on top of each other. It produces the following output below. The spacing between the two legends on the right is excessive, but I can't seem to figure out how to reduce the spacing — would really appreciate help on how to achieve this.

```
base1 = rep_crk.plot(column='pct_rep_crk', cmap='Oranges', legend=True,  figsize=(18, 16), 
                        vmin=0, vmax=1, legend_kwds={'shrink': 0.3, 'label':'Percent Rep Cracked', 'orientation':'vertical','pad':0}, hatch='.', aspect=1)
base2 = rep_pk.plot(ax=base1, column='pct_rep_pk', cmap='Purples', legend=True,  figsize=(18, 16), vmin=0, vmax=1, 
                    legend_kwds={'shrink': 0.3, 'label':'Percent Rep Packed', 'orientation':'vertical', 'pad':0})
                    
districts.plot(ax=base2, edgecolor='black', linewidth=1, facecolor='none')
plt.title('Percent of Republicans Packed and Cracked Relative to 1055 Comparators')
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('rep_heatmap.jpg', dpi=300)
```

[image]

Comment: You might try to experiment with small negative `pad` values. Maybe `legend_kwds={...,'pad':-0.1}`.  Note that for what here is called a `legend`, the underlying matplotlib element is called `colorbar`.

Comment: Ah, thank you! A pad value of -0.08 for the base1 plot did exactly what I wanted it to do! If you want to post this as an answer feel free to.